# Do node.js event emitters have to be bound to a custom object to use them effectively?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

In node.js why do some examples of event emitters look simple like this:

```
EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
ee1 = new EventEmitter;
```

and then ee1 is used to emit and listen to events.

Yet other examples look like this:

```
EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
util = require("util");

MyFunc = function ()
   EventEmitter.call(this);
}
util.inherit(MyFunc, EventEmitter);

ee2 = new MyFunc();
```

and then ee2 is used to emit and listen to events.

Can you use ee1 to handle all events (emitting them wherever you want, for example in your custom object.).  What is the reason to bind the event emitter prototype to your own custom objects/functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently *wrong* with doing it that way, but if you plan on going down the path of `ee1`, I suggest you look into [Event Aggregator Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html). With a little careful planning, you should be able to avoid some of the gotchas with a single event bus.

Personally, I've always preferred the `ee2` way of doing things. I think it keeps things a little more organized (encapsulated).

Comment: Your clear answer and supporting article helped a lot.  I suspected that was the case, but wasn't sure.  I may end up with a combination of both patterns.  Some generic events and some encapsulated where it makes sense. Now I also know what it's called (event aggregator pattern). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that your object *is* an `EventEmitter`. Using your names given, this lets you do something like:

```
ee2.on('some-event', ...);
```

while also using your object normally:

```
ee2.myOwnFunction();
```

Comment: Yes, but do you have to do it that way to use them effectively?  Can you just keep it simple by having ee1, in my example, as your event emitter object instead of replacing the prototype to your various custom objects/classes and having them emit via their own prototype functions?

Comment: I'd argue that you do, yes. Using `ee1` raises the question: how do other parts of your code access that instance? You'd have to pass both your object and its event emitter, or pass an object with an event emitter as a property. Neither is particularly fluid. Most importantly, both violate the most common pattern for `EventEmitter`, which is to extend the prototype. Now, you *could* add your own properties and functions to `ee1` instead of writing your own constructor, but this only works for very simple objects (since, well, you wouldn't have a constructor).

Comment: ee1 would be available since it's global or in the module, or can be made available via a closure.

Comment: Globals are a bad idea for reasons you'll find with a quick Google search. If your emitter is only available in some local scope, then that *works*, but it's probably the wrong tool for the job. It also means you can't later listen to events from outside that scope. That emitter might be better built into a *different* object. In other words: If you're really just calling a function in local scope, just *call the function* instead of adding a layer of abstraction (which can't be used effectively anyway, since it's scoped).

Comment: Well, all javascript programs need at least one global object (your code).  ee1 would just be carried on that global object and available to all functions and objects in your code.  I'm still looking for a definative answer to my original question.

Comment: I've explained how the extending pattern is used to achieve encapsulation. If you really want to use a globally scoped emitter, you *can*, but that's almost always a poor design. The emitter itself will work fine if you instantiate it from `EventEmitter`. However, this isn't done in practice for reasons I've enumerated. (You *can* build a car without an engine and push it around... but you really shouldn't.)

Comment: So I think you're saying I can use the first pattern and use event emitters effectively across all objects and functions ("if you really want to") within, for example, my library (defined globally) and don't have to change the prototype of my custom objects/classes? But your opinion is that it's poor design for reasons I don't fully understand yet. I'm not getting the car/engine analogy and I certainly don't want to use functions instead since the whole point of event emitters is to enable non-blocking asynchronous activity (especially with respect to I/O).

Comment: `EventEmitter` isn't for facilitating asynchronous activity; you can just use `Process.nextTick()` for that, or some higher-level libraries (e.g. async) that use it. Events can still be executed synchronously!